# how to remove space before and after sub tag

Tags: html, css, tags, word-spacing

ok so I want to remove the space between two words created by a sub word in between using css. the following two images will demonstrate what I'm trying to do perfectly.

change [this](http://imgur.com/ytTyBSN) to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWIUL.jpg).

Comment: Why don't you post your code

Comment: well it's not that complicated: first<sub>middle</sub>last

Comment: If it's not that complicated, you should have no trouble posting the code.

Comment: @user2218567 Being smug is not the way to go if you want a fellow developer to help you. After all, you are the one with a problem that needs to be solved...

Comment: @RenevanderLende I wasn't being smug until someone who was clearly not here to contribute posted a smug comment (I had already posted my code by time he was making his comment asking for the code). By the way, I want you to look at the -2 rating on my question. The problem isn't me posting a "smug" comment. It's people who downgrade a question not based on its merit, but by their perception of the tone of the poster.

Comment: Understand what you are getting at, but when you have a look at other Q&A's on SO then you you know that you should at least have posted some work already done so they can have a look at it. Failing to do so and reacting like you did is considered smug. So, why don't you post a fiddle of what you have done so far? Then we can have a look where you are going wrong/needs to be corrected...

Comment: @RenevanderLende I don't get what's so difficult to understand here. Please read these comments again. My comment is the second one and it includes the "code". Ian's is the third comment telling me that I "should have no trouble posting the code" if it is not that complicated. I know Ian had read the code because he was directly responding to the comment that included the code. Maybe this will clear things up and I can finally stop explaining my reasons for being "smug" in response to someone who was being smug to me.

Comment: You are right, a total waste of time indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be pulled off by setting the position of the sub text to absolute and setting where you want it to be. Ive made a plunker so you can see what i've done but it looks like this

```
<style>
p{
  font-size:2rem;
}
p > sub{
  color:green;
  position:absolute;
  top:7.5rem;
  left:4rem;
}
</style>
<p>First <sub>Middle</sub> Last</p>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/5UCHcHn0PuNn1oh4aWvc